# How to adjust pen sensitivity for brush size and not shade pressure?

Tags: texture-painting

I need to change the pen pressure in texture painting from opacity of the brush to the size of it.

Is it accomplishable in blender?

[image: object being texture painted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn on the pressure sensitivity for the *Radius* and disable it for the *Strength*. Those options are found in the [brush settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/painting/texture_paint/introduction.html#brushes-settings) in the tool shelf. It is the little button on the right of the *Radius* and *Strength* fields. I highlighted them in red in the image below.
[image: brush options]