# How do I turn off pen pressure for texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

I have a drawing tablet, and I can't figure our for the life of me how to turn off the pressure sensitivity for drawing in texture paint mode. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF9Tw.png

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47842/how-to-adjust-pen-sensitivity-for-brush-size-and-not-shade-pressure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press this icon, you want it deselected just like in this picture.
[image: Solution for 2.9]